# Working with banana-rdf

Tags: scala, rdf, banana-rdf

Does anyone have an example on how to properly integrate banana-rdf into a project?

Based on the example on how to use a SPARQL engine, I have tried to set up something for my project, but I get an error that I don't know how to resolve.

```
import java.net.URL
import org.w3.banana.jena.JenaModule
import org.w3.banana.{SparqlHttpModule, SparqlOpsModule, RDFOpsModule, RDFModule}

object SparqlService extends RDFModule with RDFOpsModule with SparqlOpsModule
with SparqlHttpModule with JenaModule

import SparqlService._
import SparqlService.sparqlOps
import SparqlService.sparqlOps._
import SparqlService.sparqlHttp.sparqlEngineSyntax._
import SparqlService.ops._

val endpoint = new URL("http://dbpedia.org/sparql/")
val query = parseSelect("""
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?language WHERE {
 ?language a ont:ProgrammingLanguage .
 ?language ont:influencedBy ?other .
 ?other ont:influencedBy ?language .
} LIMIT 100
                        """).get

val answers: Rdf#Solutions       = endpoint.executeSelect(query).get
val languages: Iterator[Rdf#URI] = answers.iterator map { row =>
  row("language").get.as[Rdf#URI].get
}

println(languages.to[List])
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error and I don't get why.

> Error:(27, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter fromPG:
>   org.w3.banana.binder.FromPG[org.w3.banana.jena.Jena,com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_URI]
>   row("language").get.as[Rdf#URI].get

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `import org.w3.banana.binder.URIBinder._`